# How should I make my blocks keep their color even if the global color changes?

Tags: c++

I am creating a drawing app with oclPixelGameEngine, and I can't figure out how I should make my blocks(pixels) keep their color, even after the global colors change, when I change the global colors now, every already drawn block changes its color.
*EDIT I forgot to mention this code is executed every frame, and the colors aren't, they are defined only at the start, and when I press some key, they change.

I have tried making a variables inside the for loop, still the problem persists.

```cpp
class Example : public olc::PixelGameEngine
{
public:
    Example()
    {
        sAppName = "RandomStuff";
    }

private:
    sCell* world;
    int nWorldWidth = 16;
    int nWorldHeight = 16;

public:

    int fColors[12] =
    {
        255,0,0,
        0,255,0,
        0,0,255,
        255,255,255

    };

    int rColor = 255;
    int gColor = 255;
    int bColor = 255;

    int fColorsPos = 0;

    bool colorsSet = false;

    bool OnUserCreate() override
    {
        // Provede se hned po zapnutí

        world = new sCell[nWorldWidth * nWorldHeight];

        return true;
    }

    bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime) override
    {
        // Zapne se každý snímek

        float fBlockWidth = 1.0f;
        float fSourceX = GetMouseX();
        float fSourceY = GetMouseY();

        if (GetMouse(0).bReleased)
        {
            int i = ((int)fSourceY / (int)fBlockWidth) * nWorldWidth + ((int)fSourceX / (int)fBlockWidth);
            world[i].exist = !world[i].exist;
        }

        if (GetKey(olc::Key::RIGHT).bPressed) {
            rColor = fColors[fColorsPos];
            gColor = fColors[fColorsPos + 1];
            bColor = fColors[fColorsPos + 2];
            fColorsPos += 3;
            if (fColorsPos > 3*4-1)
                fColorsPos = 0;
        }

        //Renderování

        Clear(olc::BLACK);

        for (int x = 0; x < nWorldWidth; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < nWorldHeight; y++)
            {
                if (world[y * nWorldWidth + x].exist)
                        FillRect(x * fBlockWidth, y * fBlockWidth, fBlockWidth, fBlockWidth,olc::Pixel(rColor, gColor, bColor));
            }

        return true;
    }
};
```

When I created the for loop color variables, I expected them to stay constant for every block, but the blocks still change their colors.

Comment: remember the color when you draw it in so when it is redrawn you can use the old color.

Comment: thats exactly what i want to do, but i have no idea how

Comment: i'd need to see more of the revelant code to help you further.

Comment: edited my post, hope that helps, thanks

Comment: The code is somewhat confusing, in which part of the function do you change the 'global' color? Is it on the block of code at `if (GetKey(olc::Key::RIGHT).bPressed) {` ?

Comment: add a color member to `sCell`?

Comment: exactly, and when i do, i want my code to not change already created blocks, but the blocks that will be created

Comment: Oh, I understand. As Thomas has said, you will need to allow sCell to store their own local colors. Currently, what is probably happening is your sCells are pointing to the rColors, etc., and when those change, all the sCells change their colors. You may need to implement a color variable for each sCell so they can store their own colors instead.

Comment: alright, i wouldnt ever think of that, even when i have no idea how to do it, thank you very much kind stranger, ill try.

Comment: Do you have code for how sCell is implemented? Perhaps we can help guide you on how to implement it in sCell.

Comment: `FillRect(x * fBlockWidth, y * fBlockWidth, fBlockWidth, fBlockWidth,world[y * nWorldWidth + x].pixel);`

Comment: I really dont use all the variables inside the sCell, i should delete them, im sorry if i  confused you

Comment: It's fine,. Does sCell have any color-related attributes?

Comment: it doesnt, the color attributes are only given when `FillRect(x * fBlockWidth, y * fBlockWidth, fBlockWidth, fBlockWidth,olc::Pixel(rColor, gColor, bColor));` executes

Comment: @JameEnder oh, I meant whether sCell has any extra attributes, like colors. I have provided an implementation that adds functionality on the side, perhaps that could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could implement, as a hack, some 'colorCells' to your code, if sCells does not provide a color Palette. (Although the best implementation is to figure out/add color as variables to the sCell class, for the cleanest code).

```
class colorCells
{
private:
    int rColor = 255;
    int gColor = 255;
    int bColor = 255;
public:
void setColors(int r, int g, int b) {
    rColor = r;
    gColor = g;
    bColor = b;
}

int getR() {
    return rColor;
}
int getG() {
    return gColor;
}
int getB() {
    return bColor;
}
```

And you would implement that alongside your code, like so:

```
class Example : public olc::PixelGameEngine
{
public:
    Example()
    {
        sAppName = "RandomStuff";
    }

private:
    sCell* world;
    colorCell* worldColor;
    int nWorldWidth = 16;
    int nWorldHeight = 16;

public:

    int fColors[12] =
    {
        255,0,0,
        0,255,0,
        0,0,255,
        255,255,255

    };

    int rColor = 255;
    int gColor = 255;
    int bColor = 255;

    int fColorsPos = 0;

    bool colorsSet = false;

    bool OnUserCreate() override
    {
        // Provede se hned po zapnutí

        world = new sCell[nWorldWidth * nWorldHeight];
        worldColors = new colorCells[nWorldWidth * nWorldHeight];

        return true;
    }

    bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime) override
    {
        // Zapne se každý snímek

        float fBlockWidth = 1.0f;
        float fSourceX = GetMouseX();
        float fSourceY = GetMouseY();

        if (GetMouse(0).bReleased)
        {
            int i = ((int)fSourceY / (int)fBlockWidth) * nWorldWidth + ((int)fSourceX / (int)fBlockWidth);
            world[i].exist = !world[i].exist;
        }

        if (GetKey(olc::Key::RIGHT).bPressed) {
            rColor = fColors[fColorsPos];
            gColor = fColors[fColorsPos + 1];
            bColor = fColors[fColorsPos + 2];
            if (worldColors[y * nWorldWidth + x].exist) {
                worldColors[y * nWorldWidth + x].SetColors(rColor, gColor, bColor);
            }
            fColorsPos += 3;
            if (fColorsPos > 3*4-1)
                fColorsPos = 0;
        }

        //Renderování

        Clear(olc::BLACK);

        for (int x = 0; x < nWorldWidth; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < nWorldHeight; y++)
            {
                if (world[y * nWorldWidth + x].exist) {
                    auto sColor = worldColors[y * nWorldWidth + x];
                    FillRect(x * fBlockWidth, y * fBlockWidth, fBlockWidth, fBlockWidth,olc::Pixel(sColor.getR(), sColor.getG(), sColor.getB()));

                }
            }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Hopefully that gives you a rough idea about things, the better way to implement it is probably to make colorCells use a tuple to store the colors, but this should be enough to help you understand how to store the colors for now.

Hope that helps!